# JPGraph : how to hide plot line when going above x-axis?

Tags: php, jpgraph

I set custom scale for my plot line in JPGraph, using :

```
$graph->SetScale('linlin', 60,200);
```

You can see the result here : http://screencast.com/t/jMKHg1XUis

The display is correct but i would want to hide the plots that come out of the range (below x-axis).
Can't find anything about a such feature in the documentation.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you haven't accepted Eduardo Galván's answer?

Comment: No reason, i missed the tick box to validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class reference for **Graph** has a *SetClipping* function. From the documentation:

> Enable or disable clipping outside the plot area. If clipping is
>   enabled then only the part of the graph exactly inside the plot area
>   will be visible.
>
> Clipping may come in handy when you for example set a manual scale and
>   have data points outside the specified range.
>
> By default clipping is disabled.
>
> Note 1: Clipping is only supported for graphs at 0 or 90 degrees
>   rotation and will generate an error message if enabled together with
>   any other angle.
>
> Note 2: The clipping is implemented with a O(1) algorithm in terns of
>   data size.

You need to enable clipping by calling the function:

```
$graph->SetClipping();
```